# Can someone help me in how to write a query to display the table in the below given format

Tags: mysql, sql

### Problem summarization

Generate the Output Table as shown below for the Brand table.

Brand Table

| Brand | Customer |
| --- | --- |
| KFC | A |
| Pizza Hut | A |
| Dominos | A |
| PVR | B |
| KFC | B |
| Dominos | C |
| Pizza Hut | C |
| PVR | D |
| PVR | E |
| Dominos | D |
| Pizza Hut | B |

Output table

| Brand1 | Brand2 | C1 | C2 | No_Common_Customers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dominos | KFC | A | null | 1 |
| Dominos | Pizza Hut | A | C | 2 |
| Dominos | PVR | D | null | 1 |
| KFC | Pizza Hut | A | B | 2 |
| KFC | PVR | B | null | 1 |

In Output table, No_Common_Customers column basically shows how many customers visited both Brand1 and Brand2. C1 and C2 columns represents 1st customer name and 2nd customer name respectively, who visited both Brand1 and Brand2. If only one customer visited both the brands then only his name will be displayed in one of the columns, while the other column contains NULL.

I've tried with below code:

```
select b1.Brand Brand1, b2.Brand Brand2, b1.Customer c1, b2.Customer c2
from brand b1 join
brand b2
where b1.Brand <> b2.Brand
group by Brand1, Brand2;
```

It give me this output:

| Brand1 | Brand2 | C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pizza Hut | KFC | B | A |
| Dominos | KFC | D | A |
| PVR | KFC | E | A |
| Dominos | Pizza Hut | D | A |
| PVR | Pizza Hut | E | A |

Looking forward for the early response as possible.

Comment: Your GROUP BY is invalid and expected to raise an exception. (Seems like your db is in compatibility mode.)

Comment: Use `ON` clause for join conditions. (JOIN without ON is product specific and not portable. Better to learn correct syntax from the beginning.)

Comment: @jarth can you please help me in writing the correct query for this?

Comment: What's the expected result if two brands have 3 common customers?

Comment: @jarth We have to find between 1 and 2 (1 and 2 inclusive) total number of common customers for brand 1 and brand 2 both. That's why only c1 and c2 columns are there and not c3 or more than that. I hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: @jarth if you see the data we have atmost 2 common customers for both brands (0,1,2) but not more than 2.

Comment: What's the algorithm behind that query? In which cases should the result table contain `null` or any of the numbers in the column `No_Common_Customers`?

Comment: @NicoHaase if only one customer visit both Brand1 and Brand2 then his name will be displayed in c1 column and c2 column remains NULL. Similarly, If two different customers visit both Brand1 and Brand2 then their respective names will be displayed in c1 and c2 columns. And, No_Common_Customers column basically is the total number of common customers (sum) visited both Brand1 and Brand2.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: @NicoHaase I've added description above my code. Please check and let me know if there are any other clarifications needed.                                                             Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This query might work for you.

```
select a.Brand B1, b.Brand B2, min(a.Customer) C1, case when max(a.Customer) != min(a.Customer) then max(a.Customer) else null end C2, COUNT(DISTINCT a.Customer) No_Common_Customers
from brand a 
join brand b on a.Brand < b.Brand and a.Customer = b.Customer
group by a.Brand, b.Brand
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this output. It is correct.